# R strsplit before ( and after ) keeping both delimiters

Tags: regex, r, delimiter, strsplit

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
x <- "01(01)121210(01)0001"
```

I want to split this into a vector so that i get the following:

```
[1] "0" "1" "(01)" "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "0" "(01)" "0" "0" "0" "1"
```

The (|) could be [|] or {|} and the number of digits between the brackets can be 2 or more.

I've been trying to do this by separating on the brackets first:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[\\]\\)\\}])", perl=T))
[1] "01(01)" "121210(01)" "0001"

or unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=[\\[\\(\\{])", perl=T))
[1] "01(" "01)121210(" "01)0001"
```

but I can't find a way to combine the two together.
Then, I was hoping to split the elements not containing the brackets.

I'd be really grateful if someone can help me out with this or know of a more elegant way to do this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another way:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, '\\([^)]*\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?=)', perl=T))
# [1] "0"    "1"    "(01)" "1"    "2"    "1"    "2"    "1"    "0"    "(01)" "0"    "0"    "0"    "1"
```

`\\([^)]*\\)` matches anything in parentheses, and `(*SKIP)(*F)` tells the regular expression engine to fail on this pattern and if it finds that pattern in the string, do not re-test that part of the string using the alternative pattern on the other side of the `|`. The pattern on the other side of the `|` is `(?=)`, and this matches the space between characters.

Comment: I really liked this answer too, but it seems I can only select one. Really sorry about this.
BTW, how would I modify this to use { } or [ ] ?

Answer (score 4):

Just change the PERL option to TRUE and split the input string based on the below pattern.

```
(?<!\(|^)(?!\)|\d\)|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pN7yM2/2)

R regex would be,

```
"(?<!\\(|^)(?!\\)|\\d\\)|$)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without zero width look ahead/behind expressions using `strapply` in the gsubfn package.  The regular expression matches a digit or a ( until the next ).

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(x, "\\d|\\(.*?\\)", c, perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

giving:

```
 [1] "0"    "1"    "(01)" "1"    "2"    "1"    "2"    "1"    "0"    "(01)"
[11] "0"    "0"    "0"    "1"
```

**Note:** In the example shown in the question the part inside (...) is always two digits. If that is always the case it can be simplified further to:

```
strapplyc(x, "\\d|\\(...")[[1]]
```

**UPDATE** Added note.

Comment: In this case why not use `gregexpr`?

Comment: Because of simplicity.

Comment: `grexexpr` alone is not a solution.  Obviously the solution shown here is simpler.

Comment: I was asking you for the same pattern (obviously). In other words something like that: `m<-gregexpr("\\d|\\(.*?\\)", x)
regmatches(x, m)`

Comment: That involves extracting indexes and then applying a second operation on it - not exactly simple when it can be done in a single command.  Also if you want to do something with each output component `c` can be replaced with an arbitrary function without much additional complexity.

Comment: Ok, in other words it allows to map the result array in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

An other possible way:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, '(?!\\(?\\d*\\))', perl=T))
```

Shorter but, less efficient than Matthew Plourde way

or a way like G. Grothendieck wrotes:

```
m<-gregexpr("\\d|\\([^)]*\\)", x)
regmatches(x, m)
```