# Split string on special character

Tags: regex, r, string, split

I have a string (fasta format), something like this:

```
a = ">atttaggacctta\nattgtcggta\n>ccattnnnn\ncccatt\n>ttaggccta"
```

and would like to seperate at character `>`, filter out the newlines and put the thre substrings seperated by `>` into a vector or list with three elements:

`>atttaggaccttaattgtcggta`
`>ccattnnnncccatt`
`>ttaggccta`

I tried `strsplit`:

```
unlist(strsplit(a, "(?<=>)", perl=T))
```

but this puts the delimiter `>` at the end of the each string.

I found related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493081/r-split-on-delimiter-split-keep-the-delimiter-split) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160197/r-strsplit-before-and-after-keeping-both-delimiters) but I can't really get it to work without making a complicated construct.

Is there a simple solution to do this in one go?

Comment: _"on one go"_ can also == _"unreadable for your future self or for others you share code with"_. Code is meant for humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only contains a lookbehind that matches any empty location after a `>`, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN4lH6/1). The engine processes a string from left to right, checks if there is a `>` to the left of the current location, and then returns a valid empty string match if `<` is found.

You may use `(?<=[^>])(?=>)` regex:

```
> res <- unlist(strsplit(a, "(?<=[^>])(?=>)", perl=T))
> res
[1] ">atttaggacctta\nattgtcggta\n" ">ccattnnnn\ncccatt\n"        
[3] ">ttaggccta"  
> gsub("\n", "", res, fixed=TRUE)
[1] ">atttaggaccttaattgtcggta" ">ccattnnnncccatt"        
[3] ">ttaggccta"
```

The pattern matches a location that is preceded with a non-`>` char and is followed with `>` char.

Note that using a lookbehind pattern only with `strsplit` often leads to unexpected behavior. See [*Why does strsplit use positive lookahead and lookbehind assertion matches differently?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575221/why-does-strsplit-use-positive-lookahead-and-lookbehind-assertion-matches-differ)

Comment: I think they also want to remove the line breaks within each vector

Comment: Ah, I see. I have added a `gsub` as the second step to remove newline symbols.

Comment: Thanks, this works. So `(?=>)` is a lookbehind for character `>`? And what exactly does `(?<=[^>])` do?

Comment: `(?=>)` matches any position/location  (empty string) that *is followed with `>` char*. `(?<=[^>])` matches (and requires) a non-`>` char before the current  empty position/location (so it will never match at the beginning of the string). If you need to also match at the start of the string, use a negative lookbehind, `(?<!>)`, but I doubt you need an empty item in the resulting vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

a <- ">atttaggacctta\nattgtcggta\n>ccattnnnn\ncccatt\n>ttaggccta"

stri_replace_all_regex(a, "\\n", "") %>% 
  stri_extract_all_regex("(>[[:alpha:]]+)") %>% 
  unlist()
## [1] ">atttaggaccttaattgtcggta" ">ccattnnnncccatt"         ">ttaggccta"
```

If one must use base only:

```
a <- gsub("\\n", "", a)
unlist(regmatches(a, gregexpr("(>[[:alpha:]]+)", a)))
```